# Why laravel jobs are not being stopped even though I stop the supervisor?

Tags: php, laravel

I have the following `supervisor.conf` that is used to run my jobs:

```
[program:laravel-worker]
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
command= php artisan queue:work --sleep=5 --tries=5
autostart=true
autorestart=true
numprocs=4
stopwaitsecs=5
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/home/ubuntu/laravel-worker.log
```

And I run the following job:

```
namespace App\Jobs;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;

class DelayJobTestJob  implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public function handle(): void
    {

        sleep(rand(5,6));
        Log::channel('jobs')->debug("Job Termination test jobId: ".$this->job->getJobId());
    }

}
```

Then I simulate job dispatch via running on tinker:

```
while(true){ App\Jobs\DelayJobTestJob::dispatch(); }
```

Then I try to terminate my jobs via:

```
sudo supervisorctl stop laravel-worker:*
```

But even though on suspervisor the jobs have been stopped (according to logs):

```
$ tail -f /home/vagrant/laravel-worker.log
[2020-01-21 11:58:44][57] Processed:  App\Jobs\DelayJobTestJob
[2020-01-21 11:58:44][61] Processing: App\Jobs\DelayJobTestJob
[2020-01-21 11:58:44][58] Processed:  App\Jobs\DelayJobTestJob
[2020-01-21 11:58:44][62] Processing: App\Jobs\DelayJobTestJob
[2020-01-21 11:58:46][59] Processed:  App\Jobs\DelayJobTestJob
[2020-01-21 11:58:46][63] Processing: App\Jobs\DelayJobTestJob
[2020-01-21 11:58:49][61] Processed:  App\Jobs\DelayJobTestJob
[2020-01-21 11:58:49][64] Processing: App\Jobs\DelayJobTestJob
[2020-01-21 11:58:49][60] Processed:  App\Jobs\DelayJobTestJob
[2020-01-21 11:58:49][65] Processing: App\Jobs\DelayJobTestJob #Last Log
```

The jobs are keep on dispatching:

```
[2020-01-21 12:07:28] local.DEBUG: Job Termination test jobId: 438  
[2020-01-21 12:07:29] local.DEBUG: Job Termination test jobId: 439  
[2020-01-21 12:07:31] local.DEBUG: Job Termination test jobId: 440  
[2020-01-21 12:07:33] local.DEBUG: Job Termination test jobId: 441  
[2020-01-21 12:07:33] local.DEBUG: Job Termination test jobId: 442  
[2020-01-21 12:07:35] local.DEBUG: Job Termination test jobId: 443  
[2020-01-21 12:07:36] local.DEBUG: Job Termination test jobId: 444  
[2020-01-21 12:07:38] local.DEBUG: Job Termination test jobId: 446  
[2020-01-21 12:07:39] local.DEBUG: Job Termination test jobId: 445  
[2020-01-21 12:07:41] local.DEBUG: Job Termination test jobId: 447  
[2020-01-21 12:07:42] local.DEBUG: Job Termination test jobId: 448  
[2020-01-21 12:07:43] local.DEBUG: Job Termination test jobId: 449  
[2020-01-21 12:07:44] local.DEBUG: Job Termination test jobId: 450  
[2020-01-21 12:07:46] local.DEBUG: Job Termination test jobId: 451  
[2020-01-21 12:07:48] local.DEBUG: Job Termination test jobId: 452  
[2020-01-21 12:07:48] local.DEBUG: Job Termination test jobId: 453  
[2020-01-21 12:07:50] local.DEBUG: Job Termination test jobId: 454  
[2020-01-21 12:07:51] local.DEBUG: Job Termination test jobId: 455  
[2020-01-21 12:07:53] local.DEBUG: Job Termination test jobId: 456  
[2020-01-21 12:07:54] local.DEBUG: Job Termination test jobId: 457  
[2020-01-21 12:07:56] local.DEBUG: Job Termination test jobId: 458  
[2020-01-21 12:07:56] local.DEBUG: Job Termination test jobId: 459  
[2020-01-21 12:07:59] local.DEBUG: Job Termination test jobId: 460  
[2020-01-21 12:08:00] local.DEBUG: Job Termination test jobId: 461  
[2020-01-21 12:08:01] local.DEBUG: Job Termination test jobId: 462  
[2020-01-21 12:08:02] local.DEBUG: Job Termination test jobId: 463  # Last Log
```

I figured it out because the last log on `jobs` channel has time greater than the one of supervisor's and the `12:08:02` is time grater than the time `11:58:49` that does not meet the 5-second difference that I expect the last job to be.

The only way that jobs stop being dispatched is once I run:

```
php /var/www/html/artisan down
```

Do you have any idea why that happens?

Answer (score 0):

```
while (true) {
    App\Jobs\DelayJobTestJob::dispatch();
}
```

is an infinite loop, it'll push jobs on to the queue without end.

The down command suspends the scheduler though, so they stop running.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/scheduling#maintenance-mode

Comment: So what I am emulating is on how gracefully to stop temporaryliy the jobs from running till deployment is complete. Also I cannot find out why by stopping alos the supervisor the jobs keep on popping even after stopping the infinite loop with `Ctl+C`